# Probability of n zeros from exponential distribution

Tags: probability

I have a series of random discrete numbers from an exponential distribution that can take any values between zero and infinity.

What is the probability of an upcoming n number of zeros in a row?

Example: 8 1 12 5 49 38 6 1 1 2 14 30 21 0 17 0 2 1 18 7 0 0 0 0 0

What would be the probability of the last 5 zeros? What probabilistic model can I use here?

The values are coming from the daily total sales of an item, so these numbers add up from independent events. Zero volume means no sales. The daily volume can contain zeros and positive discrete values.

Thanks.

Comment: Exponential distribution is continuous.  Do you mean Poisson?

Comment: Or do you mean the floor of an exponential random variate?

Comment: We can regard it as continuous variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n\stackrel{\mathsf{i.i.d.}}\sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda)$, $n=1,2,\ldots$ and let $m$ and $k$ be positive integers. The desired probability is
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=m}^{m+k-1} \{X_i = 0\} \right) &= \prod_{i=m}^{i=m+k-1}\mathbb P(X_i=0)\\
&= \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \mathbb P(X_1=0)\\
&= \mathbb P(X_1=0)^k\\
&= e^{-\lambda k}.
\end{align}

Comment: This makes sense. The single Poisson events are multiplied. Or the multiple days of the zeros are considered a single interval, so the mean is multiplied. Either way is the same. Thanks.